# Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: jss, nextjs

I am using Sitecore 10.2. I am able to run my sample nextjs application in connected mode using the command in VS Code terminal `jss start:connected`.

But I am not able to open my application in local integrated mode and it is throwing the below error.

Error in experience editor mode/ preview mode

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.XmlConfigurationReader.ProcessPropertyNode(XmlNode propertyNode, HttpRenderEngineOptions options)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.XmlConfigurationReader.CreateOptionsFromConfig(XmlNode config)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.XmlConfigurationReader.GetAll()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.XmlConfigurationReader.GetById(String id)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RenderEngineOptionsResolver.ResolveForId(String id, RenderEngineOptions runtimeOptions)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.HttpRenderEngineFactory.CreateEngine(RenderEngineOptions options)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.ResolveRenderEngine()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

I have verified `scconfig` and other configs like `.env` and config under sitecore/config in next js app. Everything is fine. Do anyone faced such issue and how resolved such issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering an error that suggests you already have an API key with the same item ID, resulting in the error message you're seeing. If you are working with a sample site, you can resolve this issue by clearing the items from the database using the `.\clean.ps1` script and then running the project again. This script will help remove any existing items and allow you to start fresh without any conflicts.